# SSSD list allowed users only

Tags: ldap, sssd

We are using SSSD for authentication using LDAP. And I filter the user access using **simple_allow_groups** as follows:

```
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = Computer Admins
```

(**Note**: Computer Admins is a LDAP group)

Is it possible to get a list of **ONLY** allowed users using **getent** or something else??

There is an option enumeration, but this lists **all** users from LDAP. I am only interested in the **allowed** users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the simple list, you can just call getent group for each group in the list.

There is an RFE for the next version to implement what you're asking for, but it's not done yet.